# UpdateAPIView in Django not updating Image Field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In a Django Project I have simple UpdateAPIView

```
class ProfileUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileUpdateSerializer
    authentication_classes = ( CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = ((IsAuthenticated,))
```

and a simple model

```
def image_upload_fun(instance, filename):
    return 'profile_pics/user_{0}.{1}'.format(str(instance.phone_number),filename.split(".")[1])

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_fun, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
```

[image: This is how I hit request from postman]

It does neither create new file nor it updates profile_pic_field.Although through admin panel it(image) gets updated or created easily

---

My request call is

Headers:

```
Authorization:Token 7554057effce1fcbc313f9a96be99ae17efb8eaf
```

Body:

```
phone_number:92123123132
profile_pic :[[my file]]
```

serializers.py

```
class ProfileUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile_pic_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["name", "email", "phone_number","gender", "date_of_birth", "profile_pic_url"]

    def get_profile_pic_url(self, obj):
        try:
            return self.context["request"].build_absolute_uri("/").strip("/")+str(obj.profile_pic.url)
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)
            return str("")
```

Comment: Have you tried making the request using `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: In Postman on selecting X-www-form-urlencoded I dont have any option to upload file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mistake in defining fields of ProfileUpdateSerializer

I didn't included profile_pic field in the fields of the serializer

Editing the serializer to add "profile_pic" field worked to upload image

```
class ProfileUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile_pic_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["name", "email", "phone_number","gender", "date_of_birth", "profile_pic","profile_pic_url"]

    def get_profile_pic_url(self, obj):
        try:
            return self.context["request"].build_absolute_uri("/").strip("/")+str(obj.profile_pic.url)
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)
            return str("")
```

I thought the serializer was just used to show a response after update.

Answer (score 2):

By default `django-rest-framework` uses `JSONParsor`. It will not parse uploaded files. To parse files we have to use `MultiPartParser` and `FormParser` like below

```
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser


class ProfileUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileUpdateSerializer
    authentication_classes = (
        CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication,
        BasicAuthentication,
        TokenAuthentication
    )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
```

## Request using python requests

```
import requests

headers = {
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  "Authorization": "Token <your token>"
}
data = {
    "phone_number": "987654231",
    "profile_pic": open("path/to/image.png", "r").read()
}

r = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/api/end-point/", data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: no error, only other fields are updated but no change in image field

Comment: Already tried thie header, When I apply this header none of the field changes, not even fields other than profile_pic

Comment: It should work `path/to/image.png` replace it with your path. `http://localhost:8000/api/end-point/` with your api endpoint.

Comment: It should work. I've tested it on my end. It's working for me. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. Actually I didn't added profile_pic field in serializers.py as I thought that serializer fields were used for showing response only